# as.date in R does not convert years properly

Tags: r, function, as.date

I import the csv file:

```
{casesRaw<-read.csv('CasesRaw.csv')
tail(casesRaw$Date)
```

my result:

```
"12/28/2020" "12/29/2020" "12/30/2020" "12/31/2020" "1/1/2021"   "1/2/2021"
```

after conversion:

```
casesRaw$Date<-as.Date(casesRaw$Date,"%m/%d/%y")
tail(casesRaw$Date)
```

my result is:

```
[1] "2020-12-28" "2020-12-29" "2020-12-30" "2020-12-31" "2020-01-01" "2020-01-02"
```

as you can see still I have 2020-01-01 , ....
Any Idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need `%Y` for 4-digit year instead of `%y` which is for 2-digit year

```
casesRaw$Date <- as.Date(casesRaw$Date, "%m/%d/%Y")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another base R option using `gsub`

```
casesRaw$Date <- as.Date(gsub("(.*)/(.*)", "\\2/\\1", casesRaw$Date))
```